# How to expand rows in grouped data in Ag-grid angular?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to expand particular rows in table,on certain condition. But i actually want it during on-load of page, not on any click events.

The solutions i saw online are based on click events.

Can any one help me on it?

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your concern, will keep this in mind, when i ask another question. And added to that, i got an amazing answer despite my incomplete question. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to the gridReady event:

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="gridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

And then loop though the nodes and determine whether or not you want it expanded:

```
gridReady = (params) => { 
   gridOptions.api.setData([yourData]);
   gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function(node) {
     // enter your expansion criteria here
     if (node.key==='whatever') {
        node.setExpanded(true);
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @alexander, for the solution. It works well